# pdf reading in the site

Tags: php, pdf

i need to provide pdf reading in my site, but i haven't done such before, so could you tell me how i can do it(just give me an idea, or some links...). thanks

Comment: Do you want to just show pdf file on your pages or to parse it using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a static PDF file, just put it in public webcontent and give a link to the PDF file using the HTML [`<a>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_a.asp) tag. The server will worry about setting the correct response headers. E.g:

```
<a href="file.pdf">Open PDF</a>
```

If you like to embed it in a webpage, then you can use the HTML [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp) tag for this whose `src` attribute should point to the URL of the PDF file. E.g:

```
<iframe src="file.pdf" width="500" height="300"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's [Flex Paper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Just use any basic  tag and it should open fine. Better yet, add the target="_blank" to make it open in a new window.